# Is it possible create a list of items ordered in multiple columns, select a column for a maximum of items?

Tags: html, css, for-loop, django-templates

If it's too complicated or laborious I could use multi-column layout just introduced in CSS3. What do you recommend?

basically what I want to achieve in template is:

```
Elemento1     Elemento5
Elemento2     Elemento6
Elemento3     Elemento7
Elemento4
```

instead of:

```
Elemento1
Elemento2
Elemento3
Elemento4
Elemento5
Elemento6
Elemento7
```

Usually I use `{% for a in b %}{{ a }}{% endfor %}`.

I was wondering if there was a way to break the cycle and resume from another part of the same template and continue charging the elements from where it was interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the CSS3 solution, the only way you can do this is using `column-count` property..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xV2d9/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrap {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    column-count:2;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
}
```

> Note: `column-count` property is not supported widely yet.. I would
>   suggest you to break the layout programatically. For more info on support, refer [this](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) 
>   link

Comment: In fact, that's why I asked if there was a way to break the cycle and resume. do you know how can I do that?

Comment: The non-prefixed property should *always* be *after* the prefixed versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant use CSS3 column-count, then maybe something like this:
(Never actually used Django)

```
<ul><div class="col">    
{% for a in b %}{{
  {% if forloop.counter == 4 %}
    <li>a</li>
    </div><div class="col">
  {% else %}
    <li>a</li>
  {% end if %}
{% endfor %}
</div></ul>
```

CSS: (http://jsfiddle.net/Mp5Rf/)

```
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Instead of hard coding 4, may be you could use `{% widthratio b|length 2 1 %}` to get the half way point (rounded up)?